# "stiffly pop the chain-link net". Does this 'pop' mean 'put or thrust suddenly and forcefully'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> She turned from the basket and began heading the
> other way. “Um-mah,” I cried at her, my irritation
> already bubbling over, “the basket’s over here!” After a
> few steps she turned around, and from where the
> professional three-point line must be now, she
> effortlessly flipped the ball up in the air, its flight truer
> and higher than I’d witnessed from any boy or man.
> The ball curved cleanly into the basket, stiffly popping
> the chain-link net. All afternoon, she rained in shot after
> shot, as my father and I ran after her.

'pop' has many meanings.
Does this 'pop' mean 'put or thrust suddenly and forcefully'? or Just making a popping sound? or 'hit or strike'? or 'cause to burst with a loud, explosive sound' ? or 'cause to make a sharp explosive sound'?

Comment: This is missing context, as it is, it doesn’t make sense. I think it is likely talking about the net in the hoop, but am not sure.

Comment: I can't find an actual definition for "pop the net" in basketball, but [*when you are around a pure shooter and he can put the ball in consistently without touching the rim there’s a silky noise. We call it a swish but some guys can really **pop the net**. When you can do it over and over again in an empty gym it starts to sound like the crack of a whip.*](https://www.dukebasketballreport.com/2018/4/19/17255722/duke-basketball-recruiting-a-look-at-joe-girard-iii) I don't think ELL is the right sight for such obscure domain-specific jargon, which has little relevance to learning English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about domain-specific terminology - that means nothing to most native Anglophones, and has little to do with "learning English".

Comment: It's talking about the net in the hoop and the pop is a transitive verb here. So the question was "the use of the verb pop".

Comment: pop the net means to put the ball through the net in one go, cleanly. I see no reason to close this question. Lots of people ask obscure questions. Gees. And I think it comes from the whooshing pop noise one can hear when it does.

Comment: @FumbleFingers how is an English learner to know whether the phrase they encounter is *domain-specific terminology*? Especially since the quote doesn't seem to come from a thesis on basketball minutiae, but from some sort of story.

Comment: This is apparently some kind of Korean drama story - possibly fan-fic. Like it or not folks, sport lingo is domain-specific, and not something we all share in common. I think we can answer the question, though.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski: Why does that matter? It should be obvious ***by now*** that hardly any native speakers would understand the usage being queried, and that it's therefore not a useful thing to learn *unless* you're a committed basketball fan. I don't criticize the OP here for failing to realise that it was obscure domain-specific terminology (though you don't have to be an expert to search for dictionary definitions and/or search Google Books for "pop the net"). I just don't think *future* visitors to this site will be needing this "definition", even if we can in fact provide it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but if it's jargon, it's specifically *not* answerable with a dictionary (in fact, if it were it should be closed - making your proposal a bit of a catch 22...). And frankly I'm not sure myself if it's jargon or just an uncommon idiom - Googling the phrase brings up other contexts, and Googling '"pop the net" basketball' brings up basketball sites because *duh*, that's what I put in there - so I'm definitely not in favor of penalizing OP for not knowing.

Comment: To repeat myself - I imply / intend no "penalising" of the OP for asking what I consider to be an Off Topic question. If four other users agree with my position, the question will get closed - but I haven't *downvoted*, or done anything else that would reduce the OP's rep. The possibility that OP won't be able to ***earn*** any more rep from this Q *if it gets closed* doesn't really strike me as a "penalty", if in retrospect we decide it shouldn't have been here anyway.

Comment: To "pop the net" in basketball is no more obscure that "hit a homer run" in baseball or at least not much more obscure. It is sports jargon, yes, but widely known and used. It should not be closed on that ground.